# Inserting a form (input and button) inside li elements of a bootstrap navbar while maintaining inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a basic bootstrap navbar that has a search bar in the middle of the bootstrap li elements. However, when I do this, it causes the text after the form to jump to the next line. I've tried messing with different classes, but I can't seem to figure this out. Below is an example of what's going wrong. Comment out the `<form>` and everything looks okay.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyf2ddoc/

Thanks for the help!

```
    <head>
<link rel= "stylesheet" href= "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src= "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "sidebar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
              <div class = "navbar-header">
              <a href="#" class = "navbar-brand">BookMaps</a>
              <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span></button>
              </div>
              <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                  <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href = '#'>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href = '#'>Contact</a></li>


                  </ul>
                  <span class = "addBookSpan">
                      <form class="navbar-form">

                      <span class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" style="display:inline" class = "form-control inputAB" id="addBook" placeholder = "Add a Book" >
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-default" id="addBookButton">Submit</button>
                          </span>
                      </span>
                      </form>
                  </span>
                    <ul style="display:inline" class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a>BOOK</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aXOZEXi/2/edit OR

http://jsbin.com/yafiki/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Christina, this looks perfect!

Comment: Which one worked for you?